# Prove that the following inequality is satisfied

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let A, B, and C be positive definite autoadjoint operators on a Hilbert space H, such that $D(A)\subset D(C) \subset D(B)$. We denote $\tilde {A}=C^{-1}A$ y $\tilde {B}=C^{-1}B$ where $C^{-1}$ is bounded, $\tilde {A}$ is a positive definite self-adjoint bijection operator and $\tilde {B}$ it is a positive definite self-adjoint operator. Show that it is true that:
$${\|{\tilde {A}}^{1/2}u\|}^2+{\|v\|}^2\leq C({\|{\tilde {A}}^{1/2}v\|}^2+{\|{\tilde {A}}u+{\tilde {B}}v\|}^2)$$
for all $u, v \in H$.

Remember that:

1. $C^{-1}$ is bounded; if and only if, exists M>0 such that $\|C^{-1}u\|\leq M\|u\|$  $\forall u\in H$.
2. $A$ is a self-adjoint; if and only if, $(Au,v)=(u,Av)$(consider that $A$ is a self-adjoint, implies that $A^{1/2}$ is self-adjoint).
3. $A$ is a positive definite operator; if and only if, $ 0\leq (Au,u)$ for all $u\in D(A)$.

Comment: Better to add your attempt to the question.

Comment: @Better helow, sorry for the delay, I have tried about 8 times approximately. I have shown that the inverse operator of $\tilde {A}$ is bounded, perhaps it can be used for the test.